# File extension filter

Tags: android

I have a class and example of it's usage inside Activity. Code as below:

**FileExplorer.java**

```
public class FileExplorer {
public static final String TAG = FileExplorer.class.getSimpleName();

public List<String> getAllFilesOfDir(File directory) {
    List<String> allFiles = new LinkedList<>();
    Log.d(TAG, "Directory: " + directory.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");

    final File[] files = directory.listFiles();

    if ( files != null ) {
        for ( File file : files ) {
            if ( file != null ) {
                if ( file.isDirectory() ) {  // to folder
                    allFiles.addAll(getAllFilesOfDir(file));

                } else {  // to plik
                    Log.d(TAG, "File: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
                    allFiles.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    }


    return allFiles;
} }
```

**FileExplorerActivity.java**

```
public class FileExplorerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_explorer);



    final String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    FileExplorer explorer = new FileExplorer();
    List<String> allFiles = null;
    Log.e("QWE", "qweqwE");
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {  // mozemy czytac External storage...
        allFiles = explorer.getAllFilesOfDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    } else {
        Log.e("ASD", "Nothing");
    }
    if (allFiles != null) {
        Log.d("BENG", "File list with size of: " + allFiles.size());
        for (String file : allFiles) {
            Log.d("FILE", file);
        }
    }
```

I assume, now I need to extend FileExplorer class' code.
Should I add another condition before returning at the end of code list of files?
Or should I nest earlier another condition?

Is there any method that I can use here?
Unfortunately method endsWith is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to filter a file list, you may use something like this:

> ```
> ArrayList<String> getMessageFiles(String aDir)
> {
>     ArrayList<String> res=new ArrayList<String>();
>     File dir=new File(aDir);
>     String[] files=dir.list();
>     if(files!=null)
>         for(String afile:files)
>         {
>             File file=new File(dir,afile);
>             if(!file.isFile()) continue;
>             if(!afile.matches(".*\\.txt$")) continue;
>
>             res.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
>         }
>     return res;
> }
> ```

This method returns all '*.txt' files from a directory. It uses regular expressions in order to filter the file list of a directory.